# Stream Analytics Job Input warning

Tags: azure

I am using stream analytics job to pick record from blob storage and migrate it to Azure Sql Database, recently am getting warning in input
"To ensure that blobs are not skipped due to incorrect ordering,
blobs should be spaced apart by at least 2 seconds, 
and date partitioned blobs should be produced in an increasing order of the logical date partition."

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My question is am getting warning as "Blob 2017/04/06/11/Data_201704061102.csv may have been skipped. Blob 2017/04/06/11/Data_201704061102.csv has a lastModifiedTime : 4/6/2017 11:02:28 AM and is not newer than last seen blob 2017/04/06/12/Data_201704061237.csv with lastModified time 4/6/2017 12:37:31 PM. To ensure that blobs are not skipped due to incorrect ordering,   blobs should be spaced apart by at least 2 seconds, and date partitioned blobs should be produced in an increasing order of the logical date partition."

Comment: I received the same error (many times) while ingesting continuously exported Application Insights data. Are there any recommendations for how to work around this? I don't want the data to be sampled because it's pageView data.

Comment: I was receiving the same error for the same reason as Jon.  I opened a request with Microsoft.  Because the continuous export did not batch the exports, some blobs in my storage container were inserted at the same time, hence the warning.  Their suggestion was to create a function app to merge the same timed blobs.  Not a suggested I like.  It made me think and realized if that was the case, I don't need the stream at all (for my purposes).  In the meantime, they created a feature request to solve this problem.